# Laravel - pass input value to controller with POST

Tags: laravel, post, parameter-passing, user-input

I have a laravel form and some input number fields in it. I want to post the different values of the input fields to the controller.

```
 {!! Form::open(['action' => 'ShoppingController@addProducts', 'method' => 'post']) !!}
     @foreach($products as $product)

     // some non important other data

     <input type="number" class="form-control text-center" min="1" max="999"     value="{{ $product->quantity }}">

     @endforeach
 {!! Form::submit('ShoppingCard', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary fa fa-angle-right']) !!}--}}
 {!! Form::close() !!}
```

Okay now imagine I have 3 different products, so 3 different number inputs. Now I want to pass all the different number values from the user to the controller. Like an array. How can I do that?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: <input type="number" name="number[]" class="form-control text-center" min="1" max="999"     value="{{ $product->quantity }}"> - thats what I tried and it also worked but I don't like this way cause there is no connection between the product id and the quantity. I want something like 1:15 back - where 1 is the id and 15 the quantity

Comment: I think you need to make your question clearer, as what you're asking for isn't obvious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
<input type="number" name="quantity[{{ $product->id }}]" class="form-control text-center" min="1" max="999"     value="{{ $product->quantity }}">
```

In the controller the input `quantity` will be an array, with the product id as key.

Comment: I will try it - I tried something simmilar to that but with a name="quantity[]" -

Comment: @WellNo sorry I fixed it now, also make sure that product has a `id` field.

Answer (score 0):

Try this and you will get an array of numbers in your controller

```
<input type="number" name="number[]" class="form-control text-center" min="1" max="999"     value="{{ $product->quantity }}">
```

Comment: yeah I tried that too but my problem with this is that there is no connection between the product itself and the quantity.. I want something like 1:50, 2,15 - where 1 is the product ID and 50 the quantity

Answer (score 0):

For the form do this

```
<input type="number" name="productid[]" class="form-control text-center" min="1" max="999"     value="{{ $product->quantity }}">
```

Then inside your controller you loop through the productid post input like this

```
$product_id = $request['productid'];

foreach($product_id as $pid=>$value){

}
```

$value is the the value of each of the inputs

Comment: I will try that, give me a minute :)